# Ввод данных в TWebBrowser

Tags: webbrowser, delphi, delphi-7, borland

Здравствуйте, столкнулся с такой проблемой: компонент Twebbrowser выводит данные нормально русский отображает, но если я начинаю вводить данные то выходят коракули и спецсимволы. (при этом если вводить через браузер то все нормально) в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Покажите код которым вы вводите символы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
procedure TFormSimpleWB.MsgHandler(var Msg: TMsg; var Handled: Boolean);
var
  iOIPAO: IOleInPlaceActiveObject;
  Dispatch: IDispatch;
begin
  if not Assigned(WebBrowser1) then
  begin
   Handled := False;
   Exit;
  end;
 Handled := (IsDialogMessage(WebBrowser1.Handle, Msg) = System.True);
  if (Handled) and (not WebBrowser1.Busy) then
  begin
   if FOleInPlaceActiveObject = nil then
   begin
   Dispatch := WebBrowser1.Application;
   if Dispatch <> nil then
   begin
   Dispatch.QueryInterface(IOleInPlaceActiveObject, iOIPAO);
   if iOIPAO <> nil then
   FOleInPlaceActiveObject := iOIPAO;
   end;
   end;
   if FOleInPlaceActiveObject <> nil then
   if ((Msg.message = WM_KEYDOWN) or (Msg.message = WM_KEYUP)) and
   ((Msg.wParam = VK_BACK) or (Msg.wParam = VK_LEFT) or (Msg.wParam = VK_RIGHT)) then
   //nothing - do not pass on Backspace, Left or Right arrows
   else
   FOleInPlaceActiveObject.TranslateAccelerator(Msg);
  end;
end;
```

Вот тут выдает меняется кодировка, а именно если я закодирую строчку с присвоением Handled то все нормально, но мне нужна эта процедура. что поделать?

Answer (score 0):

Какой у вас `IE`? Если не последний, то попробуйте обновить. Выложите ваш код, попробуйте скомпилировать его на Юникодных версиях Delphi(2009+). Если можно, то и ваш `exe` файл.

p.s. Если Юникодной версии нет, то советую скачать(напр. `XE`), т.к. без Юникода сейчас тяжело.